# Issue with Outlook 2013 rule condition "From Specific Address List"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sorting, microsoft-outlook-2013, email-filter

I am an exchange administrator and I have a user who wants to filter mail based on the first letter of the sender's last name.
The only way that I have found to do that is creating a server side Address List and using the "In a specific Address List" condition.

I have created the address lists and they are updated and showing up in outlook but when I try to use them as the basis of that condition nothing gets marked.
I have been able to get it to work using the Global address list as the specified list but that doesn't really do me any good.

I am not running in cached mode and this is the first rule on my list.

Any ideas why the new Address Lists wouldn't be working?

Comment: I found that this is something that would be pretty specific to our situation.

We have students stored in the cloud on Office 365 we have mail users to represent them in our local on prem exchange server. All of the local mailboxes work fine with this set up but the mail users  do not work.

Nothing wrong with the rule itself. The issue is that mail users on those lists doesn't work for some reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is something that would be pretty specific to our situation.

We have students stored in the cloud on Office 365 we have mail users to represent them in our local on prem exchange server. All of the local mailboxes work fine with this set up but the mail users  do not work.

Nothing wrong with the rule itself.